# How to Get the Module.Function Caller

Tags: vb.net, module

I've written a series of ASP.NET pages which have several common methods among them. In my ignorance, the best way I was able to find to move those common methods to a separate file was in a Module. However, what I need is a way to identify from which page was the method called?

For example, I have a method call `WriteToErrorLog` with the following signature:

```
WriteToErrorLog(ByVal sender As Page, ByVal Source As String, ByVal Message As String, ByVal StackTrace As String)
```

Since this is in a Module, the sender Page is unknown. I would like to know if there is a way to access it? I expect that there would be since if an error occurred, the stacktrace ought to reveal the play-by-play of what brought you to the error. **Do I really need to pass in the Page or can I retrieve this and the calling function some other way?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the reference to the current HttpHandler(the page) even in a static/shared context like in a `Module`.

Following is fail-safe even outside of a HttpContext(e.g. class-library referenced from a Winforms project):

```
If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
    If page IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Do something with it '
    End If
End If
```

[HttpContext.CurrentHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler.aspx)

**Edit**: You get the name of the calling method in the following way:

```
Dim method = New StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/

Comment: O.o now that's a scrumptious morsel to file away in my brain, hehe. Now can I identify from that page object which function on that page was responsible for calling the Module? Thanks again Tim :)

Comment: @Chiramisu: side-note: you can also access the session in this way: [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which maps to the current request's session ;)

Comment: @Chiramisu: edited my answer to add the way you can get the calling method.

Comment: Fantastic stuff, thank you so much. You saved me hours of research. I really appreciate it. :)